# How do you write clean debug statements in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As my spark application grows, I have noticed that it is becoming harder to read due to real code getting comingled with code that only executes in debug mode.

```
newRDD = doSomething(initialRDD)
if (debugMode) {
    newRDD.cache
    newRDD.foreach { row => logDebug("Rows of newRDD: " + row.toString.substring(0, 200)) }
    doMoreStuff()
}
finalRDD = doSomethingElse(newRDD)
finalRDD.count
logInfo("Part 1 completed")
```

What is the best way to clean this type of situation up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a trick that I've used for that very purpose, using the "enhance my library" pattern:

```
// add "wrapper" class for RDD with new printDebugRecords method:
class RDDDebugFunction[K](rdd: RDD[K]) {

  def printDebugRecords(msgFormat: K => String): RDD[K] = {
    if (isDebugMode) {
      rdd.cache
      rdd.foreach { row => logDebug(msgFormat(row)) }
      doMoreStuff()
    }
    rdd
  }

  def isDebugMode: Boolean = ???
  def logDebug(s: String) = ???
  def doMoreStuff(): Unit = ???
}

// add implicit conversion from RDD to our new class
object RDDDebugFunction {
  implicit def toDebugFunction[K](rdd: RDD[K]): RDDDebugFunction[K] = new RDDDebugFunction(rdd)
}
```

Now, by importing `RDDDebugFunction._`, we can call our new method:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4))

import RDDDebugFunction._

rdd.printDebugRecords(row => "Rows of newRDD: " + row.toString.substring(0, 200))
rdd.count
```